# AVAsset writer failed when app goes to background

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avassetwriter

my [AVAssetWriter startWriting] gets called when the application enters background and it fails with following error:

Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x13c6cac20 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-16980 "(null)"}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-16980), NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed}

And this can happen even before applicationDidEnterBackground is called. I just need to pause the video recording when the application enters background and resume recording when the application comes to foreground later.

I also tried the beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler around my [AVAssetwriter startWriting] to buy sometime but it still fails.

What is the correct way of handling video recording when the app goes to background and comes to foreground later.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that the video is in fact composed correctly?  This error is very common when there is a problem with the settings for AVFoundation (maybe overlapping time ranges?).  I would test it first in the foreground and be 100% certain the video is building correctly before looking to the Background issue.

Comment: Yes. it works in the foreground correctly all the time. Kindly note that startwriting is failing which is at the very begining before adding any video buffers.

Comment: Can you include some more code so we can replicate the problem?

Comment: Have you fixed this issue. In my app, everything works fine when app is in foreground. Once user put down app in background and move to foreground again, then appendPixelBuffer method returns false. Please suggest how I can resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS, if the status of an `AVAssetWriter` is `AVAssetWriterStatusWriting` when the client app goes into the background, its status will change to `AVAssetWriterStatusFailed` and appending to any of its inputs will fail.

You may want to use `-[UIApplication beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:]` to avoid being interrupted in the middle of a writing session and to finish writing the data that has already been appended.

For more information about executing code in the background, see the iOS Application Programming Guide.